# Trying to Match a string in the beginning of a line then extract until same string is presented

Tags: powershell-3.0

Hello I am trying to extract a string that starts with a target "Value" then will extract all info in between, then when it see's the same taget "value" it will stop extracting. I am dealing with a txt file.

Ex:

80 E4 00 80 09 4F 07 A0 00 00 01 51 53 7F 
00 A4 04 00 00 
80 E6 02 00 22 09 A0 00 00 00 18 20 41 43 54 00 14 AD 15 C6
80 E8 00 00 C0 E2 1B 4F 0F A0 00 00 00 18 10 01 08 01 00 00
80 E8 00 01 C0 A0 00 00 00 18 20 01 04 05 00 02 08 A0 00 00
80 E8 00 02 C0 FF 00 01 00 00 00 07 0A C7 06 00 F3 80 77 01
80 E6 0C 00 4E 09 A0 00 00 00 18 20 41 43 54 0A A0 00 00 00 18 20
80 E8 02 00 21 08 A0 00 00 00 18 10 01 07 00 14 4F 7E 23 A9 73
80 E6 0C 00 2A 08 A0 00 00 00 18 10 01 07 09 A0 00 00 00 18 10
80 C0 00 00 01 00 
00 A4 04 00 0F A0 00 00 00 18 10 01 08 01 00 00 00 BA FE 02

So I want to extract from where it starts at "80 E6" and then extracts all info in between untill it says the tag of "80 E6" again.

So the Output would be:

80 E6 02 00 22 09 A0 00 00 00 18 20 41 43 54 00 14 AD 15 C6
80 E8 00 00 C0 E2 1B 4F 0F A0 00 00 00 18 10 01 08 01 00 00
80 E8 00 01 C0 A0 00 00 00 18 20 01 04 05 00 02 08 A0 00 00
80 E8 00 02 C0 FF 00 01 00 00 00 07 0A C7 06 00 F3 80 77 01
80 E6 0C 00 4E 09 A0 00 00 00 18 20 41 43 54 0A A0 00 00 00 18 20
80 E8 02 00 21 08 A0 00 00 00 18 10 01 07 00 14 4F 7E 23 A9 73

So far I have this as my script:

```
 Function Extractor(){

$firstTag = '^80 E6.*$'
$secondTag = '^80 E6.*$'

$t= foreach ($line in (Get-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\dummy.txt )) { 

$x
    if ($line -match $firstTag) {

        do {             

            $foreach.current 


            $foreach.MoveNext() > $null

        } 

        until ($foreach.current -match $secondTag)         

        $foreach.current 

#        continue

        Write-Verbose "Next match"

    }
}
$t > C:\Users\nicalder\Desktop\Project1\MasterCard_Trace\modMasterCardTraceExtracted2lined.txt

}
Extractor
```

Am I doing something wrong because this was working for me great in other instances..

Thanks!

Comment: Actaully I have just figured it out. But my reputation points are not at 10 yet so I cannot post the long solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have will “fall off the end of the file” with some input.  The test added to the” until” clause below fixes that.

This matches your output for the input.  I had to make a few assumptions about how cases would be handled in the full case.

```
Function Extractor{

    $firstTag = '^80 E6.*$'

    $secondTag = '^80 E6.*$'



    $t= foreach ($line in (Get-Content C:\temp\input3.txt)) { 

        if ($line -match $firstTag) {

            $firstMatch = $line

            $foreach.MoveNext() > $null

            $lineCounter = 2

            do  {             

                if ($lineCounter -gt 2) {

                    if ($linecounter -eq 3) {

                        $firstMatch

                         $secondMatch

                    }

                    $foreach.current 

                }

                $secondMatch = $foreach.current # only used for the second line,     otherwise its is thrown away

                $foreach.MoveNext() > $null

                $lineCounter++

           }

           until (($foreach.current -match $secondTag) -or ($foreach.current -eq    $null))

#                $foreach.current 

    #        continue

        }

    }

    $t | Out-file "C:\temp\output3.txt"

 }

Extractor
```